# What is insecure about adding salt to your plaintext before using RSA?

Tags: rsa

RSA can't be used securely as is as it is deterministic. So an encrypted "yes" always looks the same.  A simple workaround, which is apparently not secure, is to add 100 bits, say, of random salt to your plaintext before encryption. Why is this not considered secure?

Comment: Do you have a citation for that claim?

Comment: To be honest you are almost 20 years late about this. The history is long about this and we have tons of questions on this. We have RSAES-PKCS1-v1_5 padding and RSAES-OAEP. former still problematic due to incorrect coding and later is proven to be secure.

Comment: Duplicates : [RSA signature with random padding](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/108093/18298) [Why don't use random padding in RSA?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/27011/18298)

Comment: Sketch of an argument (different from that in answer to the slightly different second question linked in the above comment): even with $e=65537$ and a receiving end that does not leak anything about an attempted decryption (contrary to what happened so many times with error codes or timing variation), there's a sizable chance that the padded message is the product of two numbers both less than 64-bit, and then there is an attack with cost $2^{64}$ something that deciphers the cryptogram.

Comment: @fgrieu-modelectiontime Oh that sounds interesting. Would you be able to flesh out the math for that please?

Comment: @Simd: Look at [this answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/20087/555), Encryption / Decryption, item 3 for why we want $e$ not too small, and item 5 (and the link there) for why 100 random bits are not enough. For danger of leak on the receiving end, see e.g. [this](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/12706/555).

Comment: Adding 100 bits when the message is known to be either YES or NO is of course insecure, because the result will be either 124 or 116 bits.

Comment: @gnasher729 don't you normally pad to block sizes?  But yes you do need to pad to a fixed message length for everything in these circumstances.

Comment: It would also be a problem if there are only two different messages, one just less and one just above a block size.

Comment: @gnasher729 Yes, I get the message length problem